# Navigation Bar under the Status bar

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I need to make my navigation bar under the status bar. You can see my problem on the picture below

[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtMFp.jpg)

I want to have white background for the status bar.

(swift, please)

Comment: this is not a problem, use google

Comment: @Lu_unfortunately, I didn't found anything that fits me

Comment: @Lu_if it's not a problem for you so help me please, give me a link. I found a lot of topics but they doesn't fit me.

Comment: navigation bar comes under the status bar, r u trying to make both status bar and navigation bar white ?

Answer (score -1):

In ios 10 and swift 3,

1. Change in info.plist the row

   ```
   View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to NO
   ```
2. In AppDelegate.swift, in func didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,

   ```
     UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
   ```